# Ag-grid drag and drop an item into an editable grid cell

Tags: drag-and-drop, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there a way to **drag an item** into an editable ag-grid cell?
I could not find anything in the ag-grid documentation. I could see some examples of the entire grid cell being dragged and dropped as well as dragging and dropping rows between grids, but nothing on an editable ag grid, an item being dropped into a grid cell

Comment: Can you show some code what you have tried and explain properly what you want to achieve.. What does drag an item means. Is it a grid cell or something else.

Comment: Hi Mahi, it means dragging a text and dropping it onto a cell of an Ag-grid, which will then populate the grid cell with that text